# GetObject(xxx).Application not working/recognizing open files

Tags: excel, vba, ole

Here's a code snipped exemplifying the issue I'm having:

```
Private Sub document_open()

    Dim excelObj As Excel.Application

    Err.Clear 'just pro forma, in case there's any previous junk left

    On Error Resume Next

    Set excelObj = GetObject("Book1").Application
    excelObj.Visible = True 'not necessary, I guess but I left it there anyway, tried removing it, tried changing it to false - no difference
    MsgBox excelObj Is Nothing 'for testing purposes

End Sub
```

I inputted and ran that code on a freshly created file (Book1), not saved.  It returned a FALSE, i.e. it recognized the Excel instance with a file by that name running.  I did a ctrl+N to create another file, Book2, ran the code for "Book2," and again got a FALSE.

I then saved Book2 but left it open, ran the code again, and this time got a TRUE, meaning the script didn't recognize it as an Excel instance.  I changed it to Book1, ran it, FALSE.  I then saved Book1 (as an .xlsm, of course), ran the script with "Book1" and "Book1.xlsm," and got a TRUE.

I closed everything, made sure no Excel instances were running in the Task Manager, opened both files up, ran the script, and TRUE.

The corollary is that script recognizes an Excel instance by reference to an unsaved open file but not a saved open file.

What gives?

Comment: It does, but you need to use the workbook **full name**...

Comment: No, tried all that: every possible permutation, i.e. with the extension, without, full path, etc.

Comment: What permutation? Did you try worlbook full name? Please, show how you did it.

Comment: Come on, dude, is this a pop quiz?  "Book1," "Book1.xlsx," "ActiveDocument.Path & "\Book1.xlsx"," etc.

Comment: "ActiveDocument.Path & "\Book1.xlsx" should return the Excel Application object. If not, this only proves that you did not save "Book1" in the `ActiveDocument.Path`. Supposing that you try obtaining it as automation from Word. Otherwise, `ActiveDocument.Path` does  not have much of meaning (except Corel VBA...).

Comment: Except I did: The Word and Excel files are both saved, and in the same directory.